# boost:python does not return a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, boost-python

I have a small `Python` module written in `C++`. This module compiles well and can be imported to `Python` without any errors. These are some snippets of the code:

```
//...multiple includes

typedef variant<sqlite3 **, ... other types> VariantData; //!ONE

class ORM{
   //... private fields
   public:
       VariantData Connect(int idx){
           if(idx == 0) {
               sqlite3 * conn;
               sqlite3_open("reestr.db", &conn); 
               return &conn; //!TWO
               // how to return a pointer to conn ???
               // am I doing it right ???
           }
       }
  //... other methods

  // Python stuff
  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(corm){   
      to_python_converter<VariantData, variant_to_object>(); //!THREE
      implicitly_convertible<sqlite3 **, VariantData>(); //!THREE

  //other unimportant code
```

So, this code compiles without errors. But,please, pay attention to four lines of code, marked by `ONE`, `TWO` and `THREE`, since they are causing errors. In my interpretation at line `ONE` I define a variant datatype that can take different values with `sqlite3 **` among them. At lines `THREE` I define `Python` stuff responsible for converting variables and passing them between `C++` and `Python`. However, I get into trouble when I try to use this module in `Python`. I do it like:

```
>>> import corm
>>> c = corm.ORM(...initialization parameters...)
>>> r = c.Connect() # !ERROR
... No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: sqlite *
```

I really wonder why `Python` is talking about `sqlite *` type here, while the method itself does `return &conn;` and so returns a variable of type `sqlite3 **` (as I believe). So, in a nutshell, my question is how to return a pointer of type `sqlite3 **` from Connect method.

Comment: Why would you want to return a type of `sqlite**`? At least how you are doing it now, you are returning local memory of a function that can turn invalid as soon as you exit the function.

Comment: If I try to return `sqlite3 *` and edit `typedef variant ...` and `implicitly_convertible<sqlite3 **, VariantData>();` respectively - changing every occurrence of `sqlite3 **` to `sqlite3 *`, then I get an error message `forward declaration of 'struct sqlite3'`

Comment: The idea is that I want to return a "connection variable" from one method and reuse this connection in other methods. And I use `variant` because this connection can be of different types - that is connections to different databases.

Comment: If you _must_ return a pointer to a pointer, you'll have to allocate it yourself. I *suspect* that the type should be *sqlite3, and that at one location in your code (i don't know where), it is getting dereferenced where it shouldn't be.

Comment: In fact, there is now only one place in my code where I define `sqlite3 * conn` variable and it is exactly this line of code marked by `ONE`. So, it is even impossible now, that somewhere in the rest of the code the variable is dereferenced - there is no such a code. The whole problem is to implement what I want - return a reference to connection (of type sqlite3 **) and reuse it in other methods.

Comment: Most likely the boost::variant object is trying to remove references from the sqlite3*, try this:
`typedef sqlite3* sqlite3ptr;
typedef variant<sqlite3ptr, ... other types> VariantData;
`

Comment: I checked it. It makes no difference.

Comment: This compiles for me, so most likely the problem lies in the python bindings, not the pointer:
`struct sqlite3;
typedef boost::variant<sqlite3 *, int, char> VariantData;
VariantData vd = (sqlite3*)0xdead;
`

Comment: If I make a raw `c++` program and do what you are saying, then it also works for me. But when there is some `boost::python` stuff, it starts to crash. Just try to include `boost/python.hpp` and declare `to_python_converter` with `implicitly_convertible`. I guess, it will be a totally different situation.

Comment: I tried to do it another way and returned not a variant type, but a vector whose first element is &conn. It is really interesting, but I inspected it and discovered that if I dereference this element outside Connect method, then I will get 0. So, some `boost::python` stuff or some basic stuff hidden from the naked eye make this pointer null;

Comment: I got most to compile fine, except variant_to_object, which seems to be a user-defined class.

Comment: In my case, it is defined almost like `QString_to_python_str` here - `https://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/how-to-write-boost-python-converters/ ` with the expection, that I call it `variant_to_object` and it takes `VariantData` instead of `QString`.

Comment: And by the way, I found some workaround - using `void * temp = ::operator::new(sizeof(conn)); temp = conn; return temp'` For some reason, the converter does not like `sqlite3 *` and throws `forward declaration` error. But it accepts void pointer. So, the problem is solved with the help of void. But I wish, I knew how to implement and fix converters. At this moment this theme is rather difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution. I'm not sure whether it is good, but at least it works:

```
typedef variant<void *, ... other types> VariantData;

class ORM{
//... private fields
    public:
        VariantData Connect(int idx){
           if(idx == 0) {
               sqlite3 * conn;
               sqlite3_open("reestr.db", &conn); 
               void * ref = ::operator new(sizeof(conn));
               ref = conn;
               return ref;
           }
           ...
        }
....
};

struct variant_to_object {
    static PyObject* convert(VariantData const& v){
    return boost::python::incref(
      boost::python::object(v).ptr());
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(corm){   
     to_python_converter<VariantData, variant_to_object>();
     implicitly_convertible<void *, VariantData>();
```

But of course, I should take care of `ref` pointer and `delete` it, when it is no longer used.

Comment: You do not even need to new it here, since you immediately overwrite it. Just casting the sqlite3* to void* should work.

Comment: Can you, please, show how this should look like without a `new`?

Comment: Do you mean return `(void *) conn`?

Comment: Yes, but i used static_cast instead of a c-style cast.
It seems that my edit on your post won't show up until it is reviewed, so basically remove all 3 lines with the ref (the assignment, the new and the return, and directly return: `return static_cast<void*>(conn);`

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark! I really appreciate your help!